# How can I avoid Http protocol error 0 while WebScraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am getting this error while web scraping

> http protocol error', 0, 'got a bad status line

What does it mean? And

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

First line of HTTP (>1.0) Response is status line.

This error says that your status line is broken. It can be if server response starts with `non-RFC status line` (i don't think it can be), and if `response is version http/0.9` (no status line and headers). Server answer with HTTP/0.9 if your request (for example header lines) was broken

Check response using wireshark (or something else) and give us a bit more info about your error.